# Location isnt updated in Bukkit-Plugin

Tags: java, plugins, while-loop, location, bukkit

Im trying to write a plugin, that allows the players to fly. While they are flying, there level goes down every second, and if there level is 0, fly would turned off. But in my while loop the position isnt updated and so there level wents down, altought they are back at the ground again. I read that this is because i stop the Thread, but how can i write it in an other way, so that it is still  lightweight?
Here is my code:

```
public void onPlayerToggleFlight(final PlayerToggleFlightEvent e) {
        if(!e.getPlayer().isFlying()){
            final Player p = e.getPlayer();
            if(p.getGameMode() == GameMode.CREATIVE)
                return;
            getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                    while((p.getLevel() >= 0) && (p.getLocation().subtract(0, 1, 0).getBlock().getType() == Material.AIR)){
                        System.out.println(e.getPlayer().getLocation());
                        p.setLevel(p.getLevel() - 1);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    p.setAllowFlight(false);
                    System.out.println(p.getLocation());
                    }});
        }

    }
```

And the Levelindicator is only updated when its 0. For example my level is 8 and i start flying, 8 seconds later i fall down and my level changes. So i cant see how much time i have left to fly...
Thanks you for your answers and sorry for my bad english ;D

Answer (score 1):

The entire server is frozen while your `while` loop runs (oops!).

See how you're scheduling a task? You need to keep doing that, instead of doing it once and then using `Thread.sleep`:

```
getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(this, new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        if((p.getLevel() >= 0) && (p.getLocation().subtract(0, 1, 0).getBlock().getType() == Material.AIR)){
            System.out.println(e.getPlayer().getLocation());
            p.setLevel(p.getLevel() - 1);
            // Schedule this task to happen again in one second
            getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(YourPluginClass.this, this, 1000);
        } else {
            p.setAllowFlight(false);
            System.out.println(p.getLocation());
        }
    }});
```